# NativeGeocoderReverseResult getting error while importing in ionic4 + capacitor

Tags: angular, ionic3, capacitor

Getting error while importing NativeGeocoderReverseResult from native geocoder.I am using ionic4 with capacitor

import { NativeGeocoder, NativeGeocoderReverseResult,  , NativeGeocoderOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';
all other than NativeGeocoderForwardResult is importing without error

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins, Capacitor, CameraSource, CameraResultType, CameraDirection, Camera, Geolocation } from '@capacitor/core';
import { NativeGeocoder, NativeGeocoderReverseResult, NativeGeocoderForwardResult, NativeGeocoderOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  selectedImage: string;
  coordinates: { lat: number; long: number; };
  resultValue: any;

  constructor(private mediaCapture: MediaCapture, private alertcontroller: AlertController, private nativeGeocoder: NativeGeocoder) {
    this.getLocation();
   }

  getLocation() {
    if (!Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('Geolocation')) {
      this.alertcontroller.create({header: 'could not fetch location'});
      return;

    }
    Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(position => {
      this.coordinates = { lat: position.coords.latitude, long: position.coords.longitude};
      console.log('coordinates-oojj', this.coordinates);

    });
    const options: NativeGeocoderOptions = {
      useLocale: true,
      maxResults: 5
  };

    this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(52.5072095, 13.1452818, options)
    .then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult[]) => {
      this.resultValue = result;
      console.log('resultValue',this.resultValue)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0]))}
    )

    .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
  }


}
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you show the smallest possbile reproduction code?

Comment: ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts(5,26): error TS2305: Module '"D:/ionic-onecredit/node_modules/@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx/index"' has no exported member 'NativeGeocoderReverseResult'.

code is same as above only thing is  NativeGeocoderReverseResult is not getting imported

Comment: Why do you expect that the member is to be found in the module? Do you have correct version?

Comment: yes i am using ionic 4 + capacitor
i am following this https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-geocoder
in order to convert the latitude and longitude got from the geolocation (present in the capacitor) to address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NativeGeocoderReverseResult is not part of Ionic anymore. The plugin (native-geocoder) was updated to 3.2.0. The docs are deprecated. Its recommended to use a new import statement:

```
import { NativeGeocoder, NativeGeocoderResult, NativeGeocoderOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';
```

with the following code:

```
let options: NativeGeocoderOptions = {
      useLocale: true,
      maxResults: 5
  };

  this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(52.5072095, 13.1452818, options)
    .then((result: NativeGeocoderResult[]) => console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0])))
    .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));

  this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode('Berlin', options)
    .then((result: NativeGeocoderResult[]) => console.log('The coordinates are latitude=' + result[0].latitude + ' and longitude=' + result[0].longitude))
    .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

As you can see **NativeGeocorderReverseResult** and **NativeGeocoderForwardResult** are both replaced by **NativeGeocoderResult**.

See the source code for more information: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/4de49c37dd9bd23799b089595db998ade34a9c88/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/native-geocoder/index.ts

Comment: Thanks @Raphael Mayer.
I did the same but it is getting the error as 
**Geocoder:getFromLocationName Error: Timed out waiting for response from server**

Comment: Yes, thats a normal server timeout. Has nothing to do with your question. Maybe you use a proxy, maybe you use a vpn, maybe something other is between you and google. There is no way i can help you with that.

Comment: Its worked when i tried with my own device. I think it wont work with browser or emulator

Comment: You sure your app has internet permission?  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />. Yes, using an emulator can also be the reason.